# Face flipping and rotating like crazy when intended to "G" move and snap to an edge

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to align a face to an edge of another object. In *Edit Mode* I select the face, press  <kbd>G</kbd> and try to move it to the snapping point, sometimes with the appropriate axis (x/y/z).

When touching this point, which is marked then with a small orange circle, the face is behaving like crazy, doing flips, turns, rotations or jumps. Same happens with objects sometimes. Why can any object do a transform that in no way was intended?. When i want something to rotate, the  <kbd>R</kbd> key should have been in the workflow, and if it is not, the object should not rotate by any reason.

Comment: Do you have "Align Rotation to Target" turned on in your snapping settings?

Comment: Yes, i want that to happen WHEN rotating objects. Does it mean Blender rotates things whenever it decides, an alignment could be made, without wanting me to rotate?  That would be far from clever... Usually i prefer software that respects my input. "G" is "G", not "R"

Comment: Yes, objects will ALWAYS align their rotation when the setting is active when you're moving an object, rotating or scaling will just snap to whatever your active snap is.
Think about it, if you're rotating an object, all it does is rotate about the pivot point, scaling only scales from the pivot point, but moving an object moves it around in space but with this setting active when it snaps it will also align the Z axis of the object being moved with the "normal" of the vertex, edge or face that gets snapped. It's extremely useful for setting objects onto one another in 1 simple move.